# Difficulty Authenticating Browser Extension with Trello: How to Set Up IFrame Connector URL?

Tags: authentication, browser-extension, trello, trello-powerup, trelloapi

I'm developing a browser extension that aims to integrate with Trello. I'm encountering challenges in the authentication process. The confusion revolves around whether an "IFrame Connector URL" is required for authentication within a browser extension's Trello integration.

I attempted the authentication process using Trello's API but encountered authentication failures. I expected successful authentication to Trello's services. However, I'm unsure if this is related to the absence of an "IFrame Connector URL" or if there's another issue in the authentication process within a browser extension's setup with Trello.